# Receiving data to another table

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require('../connection.php');

    if(empty($_SESSION['admin_id'])){
       header("location:access-denied.php");
    } 

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbCandidates")
    or die("There are no records to display ... \n" . mysql_error()); 
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0){
       $result = null;
    }
    ?>
    <?php

    $positions_retrieved=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbPositions")
    or die("There are no records to display ... \n" . mysql_error()); 
    $name_retrieved=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbstudent")
    or die("There are no records to display ... \n" . mysql_error());


    $row = mysql_fetch_array($name_retrieved);
    if($row)
    {
    //get data from db
     $name = $row['student_name'];
     $gender =$row['student_gender'];
     $grade =$row['student_grade'];
     $section =$row['candidate_section'];

     }

     ?>

    <?php

       if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {

    $newCandidateName = addslashes( $_POST['name'] ); //prevents types of SQL injection

    $newCandidatePosition = addslashes( $_POST['position'] ); //prevents types of SQL injection

    $sql = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO tbCandidates(candidate_name,candidate_gender,candidate_grade,candidate_section,
    candidate_position) VALUES
   ('$newCandidateName','$gender','$grade','$section','$newCandidatePosition')" )or die("Could not insert candidate at the moment". mysql_error() );
 ?>
```

When I add new candidate that came from another table, the Candidate Name and Candidate Position is right, But the Gender, Grade and Section became the same with data. [image: Check Image]

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: **WARNING**: `addslashes` should **NOT** be used. It's not adequate for escaping SQL. If your reference material tells you to do this, get another reference immediately. This code can blow up on you in a huge way.

Comment: To format code, just indent it with four spaces.

Comment: There's insertion code here, but no display code, which is probably the origin of your display issue. I'm also wondering why displaying data requires `INSERT` operations. Maybe you mean to do some kind of `SELECT` with a `JOIN` instead?

Comment: yes i just need to fetch a data from another table but im having trouble. The Candidate Name is right and also the Candidate Position. But when it comes to Gender, Section, and Grade its not changing they all becme the same. Everyone becomes female even though i put male

Comment: what should i do sir

Comment: It's not clear where that table data is coming from. Where is it displayed?

Comment: it's from tbstudents with rows 
student_id
student_name
student_gender
student_grade
candidate_section . <td><SELECT NAME="name" id="name">select
    <OPTION VALUE="select">select name of the student which is student_name. Getting the student_name and putting it on the candidate_name on the table tbcandidate using <td><SELECT NAME="name" id="name">select
    <OPTION VALUE="select">. While they choos a student_name i also want to select other row with tbstudent to put in the tbcandidate

Comment: As always, please put the code in your question by making an edit. It can be very hard to read in comments. There's also no looping code there, so you'll need to add that as well.

Comment: the result is i succesfully put student_name and with other row to another table which is tbcandidate but the fail result is everything in gender,  grade, section are all become the same. i think they are retrieving the first data in student_section,student_grade,candidate_section

Comment: There's a lot of confusion here as to how to do this. If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com) to get specific one-on-one training.